# Chrome Inspector - Show modified changes

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I like to use the Chrome inspector to make changes to CSS and the DOM interactively, and then make the corresponding code changes after.

Is there anyway to highlight my changes in the inspector so I don't need to remember what properties I modified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list changes made to script or styles as Chrome DevTools maintains a history of the modifications. Right-click in your CSS or script file, or on the filename in the *Sources* panel, and select ***"Local modifications..."***.
However, there is no such feature for DOM editions, as far as I know.

See capture below :

[image: DevTools revision history feature]